# Using google apps script to add range to a line chart on secondary (right) vertical axis

Tags: google-apps-script, charts

I am trying to make a google apps script to show covid related graphs.
I can download data from cdc, and put them in a spreadsheet where there is a graph and it works just fine but I have a problem with axis scale.
When you try to compare a countries sum of cases to the sum of deaths for example, deaths are too few and the graph isn't right. So I am trying to find a way to add deaths in this example but have them show in secondary (right) vertical axis.
Is there a way to to this?

Edit: to be more precise
My script gets the data from ecdc, puts it in sheets, shorts it to be usable and then puts it in a sheet with a premade chart, changing the data. Number of columns isn't always constant, some may be blank.
Works fine for one category of data.
What I need is to be able to add another set of data to be able to add a range as series in the chart but in a secondary axis.

My "code" looks like this

```
    chart = chart.modify()
  .setOption("series",{0:{targetAxisIndex:0}})
  .setOption("series",{1:{targetAxisIndex:0}})
  .setOption("series",{2:{targetAxisIndex:0}})
  .setOption("series",{3:{targetAxisIndex:0}})
  .setOption("series",{4:{targetAxisIndex:1}})
  .setOption("series",{5:{targetAxisIndex:1}})

  .build()
  sheet.updateChart(chart)
```

2 problems here. 
1 It works when I change one series to right vaxis, but as soon as I do a second, first reverts to left axis.
2 I don't know how to get a list of series in the chart with their index so that even if I make it to work I must guess which series have what data

Edit: I changed the code and it now holds the changes but I still want to get a list of series in the chart with id's and series header so I know what to change.
here is an example
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_bTj8e3FZpbhdENwN9CdLYsqkJeqp313CGCJmPNtrr4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What does this have to do with Google Apps Script?

Comment: I am trying to do it in apps script. How doesn't this have to do with it?

Comment: Okay.  Then where is your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: It's a mess. I am struggling with chart = chart.modify() and then .setOption("series",{0:{targetAxisIndex:0}}) (or) .setOption("series",{0:{targetAxisIndex:1}}) but 1. I don't know how to find all the series in the chart. The number of series is not constant. 2 as soon as I change a second series targetAxisIndex, the first reverts to left axis. So, if I do .setOption("series",{0:{targetAxisIndex:1}}) and .setOption("series",{1:{targetAxisIndex:1}}) when I check the chart only series 1 is changed. Posting some on orig question now.

Comment: I can't reproduce your situation without a [mcve].

Comment: Added some code.

Comment: Can you update your question with the newest code you have and explain better what is your remaining question after you found some answer yourself?